# How to conditionally delay a scheduled automation run in Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio

I have an automation process which is scheduled to run on the **first Monday of every month**. This automation has a "Journey Builder Trigger" activity for injecting contacts to a journey.

I need to come up with a way to delay the injection of the contacts (delay the target automation schedule) for 1 day if today i.e. (the day automation runs) is a **Public Holiday**.

I've already created the process to fetch and update the public holiday dates in a separate DE.

My Idea was to add a verification step to the automation and if the counter in a separate DE (which matches with the public holiday DE and sets counter to 1 if its a holiday) is set to 1 than STOP the automation.

This process now works but the automation than needs to be manually run the next day.

I need to figure out a way to run this automation process to automatically run on the next day which is Tuesday if Monday was a holiday.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a second automation that runs on the **first Tuesday of the Month** and apply a similar verification logic -- if counter is 1 then run that Tuesday automation, else stop the automation.

Alternatively, if you have a data extension already set up with holidays, add logic within the SQL query of your Journey Data Extension to lookup that Holiday DE. Something like:

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, HolidayDate) != CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```

But you would still need to manually run on that Tuesday or have an automation run on Tuesday. The [Verification Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_verification_activity.htm&type=5) only allows you to stop the automation or send an email so either way there would need to be a second automation.

Comment: Thanks but doesn't completely solve the problem if I need to manually run the automation the next day. To run a second automation to pick up if the first one is stopped is still at-least halfway solution I will give you that!

Comment: You can schedule the second automation to run on Tuesday. Basically an inverse of the Monday automation.